# Custom sign-up form in Devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have looked at other answers on here and have yet to find one. I am creating a Rails 4 app that allows users to sign in and create a profile. I am using Devise gem for user authentication.

What I want to do is have the user also type in their name and a description of themselves during the signup process. When submit the form the database will be updated with this info as well. Here is what I have done:

1) I ran a migration to create the new columns, "name" and "description", in the users table

2) I ran rails generate devise:views. This allows me to access devise>views>registrations>new.html.erb where I included the "name" label and field. I just used the other labels and fields as a guide. I now get an error saying name_field method is undefined. Where are the other ones like email_field and password_field defined?

```
    <h2>Sign up</h2>

  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.name_field :name %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Any help in getting this working I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Check my answer below. Here's the Rails guide on form helpers http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no method on the Rails form object that says `name_field`. `name_field` is not a valid HTML form input type. Did you do find and replace? You should change

```
<%= f.name_field :name %>
```

to

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

#### UPDATE

Overriding `configure_permitted_parameters` in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, rest_of_user_attrs) }
      # you control which attributes can be updated or used for sign in here
    end
end
```

Here's more information for your perusal https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Comment: I tried you solution here and I am able to add a User entry. However, tt will create a database entry with an email and password but will not include the name. I also want the name the the user enters to go into the database too.

Comment: Override `configure_permitted_parameters` in your `ApplicationController` to add `name` to the list of permitted parameters for signing up. I updated my answer with how that part looks like

Comment: I'm happy that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

@user2623706 have you configured devise for strong parameters. That may be the problem.